# How to serve static files with connect.js with a non root mount point

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect

I have a connect server with a base of `app` in my project.
In the same folder as app I have `bower_components`

How can I get `bower_components` to be accessible under `/bower_components` on my webserver?
I don't want to put `bower_components` folder under `app`.

Also I don't want to do bases like `['app', './']`, that will just be messy and add app 2 times, as well as other files in `./` that I don't want exposed.

[Connect static](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) does not mention anything about server mount point.

I would imagine something like

```
connect.static(__dirname + 'app');
connect.static(__dirname + 'bower_components', '/bower_components');
```

But this doesn't seem to work according to the docs.

Could this be easier to accomplish in express.js for instance?

Answer (score 0):

just use [send](https://github.com/visionmedia/send). put a route and few lines of code you can have multiple public folder
just like alias. express use it to serve static files, well quite obvious
because it come from the same person.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I use connect with grunt-contrib-connect. I was hoping using a middleware was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect()
    .use(connect.static('app'))
    .use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components'))
    .use(connect.directory('app'));
```